# Proactive assist bot using microsoft bot framework

Tags: botframework, chatbot

I am planning to develop a bot using Microsoft bot framework. The reason for choosing this framework is for  integrating it with teams. The bot which i am planning to develop should do a proactive alert like when a ticket gets updated in ITSM platform the user should get notified. Can anyone please help me out with the architecture for building up this bot. Because i could see in some documentation they are suggesting to use Azure functions and Azure storage queues for proactive assist bot. Please assist. I am planning to do this using node.js SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read all about proactive messages and how to build them in the Bot Framework [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=javascript). Overall, there is a lot of useful information there on how to build your bot.

You can also reference the [blogs](https://blog.botframework.com/) and Botbuilder-Samples [repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs). The repo provides examples you can build and run teaching you what you need to know to get going. It does so in iterations graduating from basic to advanced so you achieve a full understanding.

Best of luck!

Comment: @ Steven kanberg . In notification only bots, can we perform any actions on the notification message.

Comment: @Arulvelu, can you elaborate? What kind of actions and at what point would the action take place - as it is sent or when it is received?

Comment: Lets say i am an employee and i am raising a usb access request in ITSM portal. You are my approver for this request. But you need some inputs from me. SO when you the approver wants some inputs. It comes to me as proactive message to my teams channel with action buttons like ("Updated ticket"). On clicking the button it should update ticket for me with the descriptions i am giving.

Comment: I believe I understand what you are asking and there really should be any reason you can't do this. Read over this GH issue that discusses a related issue (https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/4339#issuecomment-415510619).